# Convert MongoDB query result into JSONArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongoose

I have a MongoDB query via mongoose and the result is:

```
[
  {
    "tablename": "name1"
  },
  {
    "tablename": "name2"
  }
]
```

but I need it as JSONArray :

```
{
  "tablename": [
    "name1",
    "name2"
  ]
}
```

Is there an easy way to convert?

Answer (score 1):

The **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** can create the desired result for you. Consider the **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)** and the **[`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** accumulator operators as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "tablename": {
                "$push": "$tablename"
            }           
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "tablename": 1
        }
    }    
])
```

Sample Output:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "tablename" : [ 
                "name1", 
                "name2"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You can implement this in mongoose using the **[`aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate)** method, for example:

```
var pipeline = [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "tablename": {
                    "$push": "$tablename"
                }           
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0, "tablename": 1
            }
        }    
    ]

Model.aggregate(pipeline).exec(function (err, res){
    console.log(res);
})
```

---

**UPDATE**

Change this query to use the aggregation framework:

```
app.post('/getkost', function(request, response){ 
    var kost = new RegExp(request.body.kost,'i'); 
    Move.find(
        { tablename: { $regex: kost } },
        { tablename: 1, _id: 0 }, 
        function(err, doc) { 
            response.json(doc); 
    }); 
});
```

to this:

```
app.post('/getkost', function(request, response){ 
    var kost = new RegExp(request.body.kost, 'i'); 
    var pipeline = [
        {
            "$match": {
                "tablename": { "$regex": kost }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "tablename": {
                    "$push": "$tablename"
                }           
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0, "tablename": 1
            }
        }
    ]
    Move.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, res) { 
        response.json(res); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: its working for a find query too? I dont want to change any data

Comment: Can you show the `find()` query? You can substitute that query with the **`$match`** pipeline operator.

Comment: app.post('/getkost', function(request,response){
   var kost = new RegExp(request.body.kost,'i');
   Move.find({tablename: {$regex:kost}},{tablename: 1, _id: 0}, function(err, doc) {
   response.json(doc);
   });
  });

Comment: @Piet Check out my update, this should give you the desired result using the aggregation framework.

Comment: `"$match" : {
                 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: @Piet My bad, there was a typo in the pipeline as I forgot the enclosing braces. Try that now, should work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, when I understand it, I am more happy, but its working like a charm, BUT the link you have shown doesnt show the "$project" part, why not?

Comment: I found another error, Its an Array, but I need it as JSONObject, to change "[]" doesnt work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84111/discussion-between-piet-and-chridam).

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
var inputArr = [
  {
    "tablename": "name1"
  },
  {
    "tablename": "name2"
  }
];

var jsonArr = {"tablename": []};

for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
  jsonArr.tablename.push(inputArr[i].tablename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var json = [{
    "tablename": "name1"
}, {
    "tablename": "name2"
}]

var arr = {};
json.forEach(function(value, key) {
    var tableName = Object.keys(json[key]);
    arr[tableName] = arr[tableName] || [];
    arr[tableName].push(value[tableName]);
});

console.log(arr);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fznf0rrc/)

Keep in mind that `Object.keys()` will actually return an array - if your array contains more than one key (e.g. `{"tablename": "name1", "othertablename": "name2"}`)